# Performance problem with camel "activemq component"

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I tried to work with ActiveMQ component (inside Spring-Boot) and I ended it up with some weird 
result.

1- I sent 2000 messages from SEDA to `destinationQueue`

Here's how I did it:

```
from("file:G:/highlight").to("seda:warehouse");
// took less than a millisecond to complete



from("seda:warehouse?concurrentConsumers=20").to("activemq:queue:destinationQueue") 
// Completion time : 58 seconds
```

```
Completion time : 58 seconds
```

2- Now I try to consume these files from `destinationQueue` 
 and this is how I'm going to do it:

```
        from("activemq:queue:line1").process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
            }
        });  
// The completion time : around 1 second!
```

```
The completion time : around 1 second!
```

So my question is:

1- Why the speed is very slow, when I'm sending files to the queue? But I can consume those 
 messages so fast (in this test it was more than 50 times faster)!!!

- I did consuming and producing both on my laptop.

Any help would be really really appreciated :))

Comment: IMHO: When you send messages to the ActiveMQ queue, you put them in the database. The database is located on your hard drive (bottleneck). Reading from a database is faster than writing. And of course you can play with the settings of ActiveMQ

Comment: Wild guess (slightly different): disk-based source (file(...)) versus in-memory reading. Check how long from("file...") with a System.out.println-processor takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it thanks to [@Alexey-yakunin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5499138/alexey-yakunin) :)

When you working with ActiveMQ , If your destination is "queue" then the speed of producing messages to 
the queue is way more slower than consuming from the queue. 
It's because, like the way [@Alexey-yakunin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5499138/alexey-yakunin) said "when you send messages to the ActiveMQ queue, you put them in the database. The database is located on your hard drive (bottleneck). Reading from a database is faster than writing to it".

So to prove this theory, I did this test:

(Instead of sending messages to `queue` I sent them to `topic` without any durable subscribers)

`No durable subscribers to the topic == No databse`

```
        from("file:G:/highlight").to("activemq:topic:newVersion");
        from("activemq:topic:newVersion").process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Date date = new Date(time);
                System.out.println(date);

            }
        });
```

For `2000 messages`, It took only `3 seconds` to produce and consume all the messages.

Also These are options that I set in spring boot `application.properties` in order to get most out of activemq:

```
camel.component.activemq.broker-u-r-l=tcp://localhost:61616

// By default it is set to false so make sure you set this to true
camel.component.activemq.use-pooled-connection=true 

camel.component.activemq.transacted=false

//Remember, the messages will be lost if the broker crashes or is restarted.
camel.component.activemq.delivery-persistent=false

camel.component.activemq.wait-for-provision-correlation-to-be-updated-thread-sleeping-time=50
```

There are two other options which stimulates you to change their value , but I found them 
at best when they are set with their default values:

```
camel.component.activemq.concurrent-consumers
camel.component.activemq.max-concurrent-consumers
```

That's all :))

Comment: It's worth noting that using non-persistent messages (via `camel.component.activemq.delivery-persistent=false` means that the messages will be lost if the broker crashes or is restarted. Also, if you want the best performance from an ActiveMQ broker checkout [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/). Its performance is much better than the 5.x broker especially in high concurrency use-cases.

Comment: @JustinBertram, you are absolutely right. Different context needs different settings. Here I tried to prove the reason of why producing to a queue is way much slower than consuming from that, and as in my example I said "non-durable topic" just to remove database out of the way. And of course there are better choices than ActiveMQ , like Rabbit and Kafka.

Comment: Whether or not Rabbit or Kafka are better choices that ActiveMQ Artemis is, of course, debatable. If you're concerned with performance and high availability of your data then [this article](https://softwaremill.com/mqperf/) might be helpful.